# How to pass a Document File to UIActivityViewController i.e. Share Sheet

Tags: ios, swift, csv, ios-sharesheet

I have an iOS App which generates a CSV File and saves it to the working Documents directory of the device.  Now when a user presses a button, the UIActivityViewController Share Sheet is displayed which allows you to open send data to other apps.

My question is how do I pass this CSV file to the Share Sheet.  I know how to make this work with Text and Images, but not exactly sure how to get this to work with a CSV file.  The end result is that I want this file to show up as an attachment in any email client which is selected from the Share Sheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the code I use to open a document (word, pdf, etc.). Should work for you...

```
@IBAction func openDocument(sender: AnyObject)
{
    let interactionController = UIDocumentInteractionController(URL: documentURL)

    // (build your document's URL from its path in the Documents directory)

    interactionController.delegate = self


    // First, attempt to show the "Open with... (app)" menu. Will fail and
    // do nothing if no app is present that can open the specified document
    // type.

    let result = interactionController.presentOpenInMenuFromRect(
        self.view.frame,
        inView: self.view,
        animated: true
    )


    if result == false {

        // Fall back to "options" view:

        interactionController.presentOptionsMenuFromRect(
            self.view.frame,
            inView: self.view,
            animated: true)
    }

    // DONE
}
```

Comment: Super Cool, thx bud.  This works, except for one thing, it seems to work with some programs and not others.  Why is that?  For example, when I select GMail, the GMail Client and composer opens up, but the file is not attached to it.  On the other hand, when I select one of my File Transfer programs, it works in that case.

Comment: and another thing, why is the Apple Mail Client not showing in the Document Selection list?

Comment: I don't think there's much you can configure; the system pretty much determines the sheet's contents based on file type and installed apps, as far as I know.

Comment: By the way, the code I posted is basically Apple's sample code.

Comment: I think you may be right, I was just looking at my log files in the console and it shows the right extensions were called etc...but the plugin invalidated the contents.  So I guess there's not much I can do.  In any case, I will still accept your answer since it's technically correct, but more so out of my control due to Apple's API I guess.

Comment: @Lavvo `UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [fileURL], applicationActivities: nil)` Refer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35851118/how-do-i-share-files-using-share-sheet-in-ios