# How to share .zip file in UIActivity ViewController?

Tags: swift, uiactivityviewcontroller

```
@IBAction func clickedViewData(_ sender: Any) {
    let fileManager = FileManager.default
    let documentoPath = (self.getDirectoryPath() as NSString).appendingPathComponent("zip_2MB.zip")
    if fileManager.fileExists(atPath: documentoPath){
        let documento = NSData(contentsOfFile: documentoPath)
        let activityViewController: UIActivityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [documento!], applicationActivities: nil)
        activityViewController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView=self.view
        present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    else {
        print("document was not found")
    }
}
```

i have one Zip file i want to share as a .zip directly..but cant get proper solution to share .zip file..when i share file its share as data file.. i read some documents but cant get proper way for share zip file in activity controller.. please help to solve this problem.

Thank You

Comment: Have you tried this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35851118/how-do-i-share-files-using-share-sheet-in-ios

Comment: cant get there is image and text sharing..can you please help for this how can i use write method here and else i give mime type here..@FaysalAhmed

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35851231/5167909

Comment: finally get answer...var url = URL(fileURLWithPath: NSTemporaryDirectory() + ("My File.txt")) documento?.write(to: url, atomically: false) thank You..

Answer (score 2):

```
let fileManager = FileManager.default
        let documentoPath = ("self.getDirectoryPath()" as NSString).appendingPathComponent("zip_2MB.zip")
        let documento = NSData(contentsOfFile: documentoPath)


        var url = URL(fileURLWithPath: NSTemporaryDirectory() + ("My File.txt"))
        documento?.write(to: url, atomically: false)

        // create activity view controller
        var activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [url], applicationActivities: nil)
```

Comment: finally get answer and share sucessfully any document in ActivityViewController.